# angularjs Routing isn't working on

Tags: angularjs

Can any one tel me what is the problem with this Code

```
angular.module("Appp",["ngRoute"])
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/add', {
        templateUrl: "template/addContact.html",
        controller: "addContact"
    })
})
.controller('addContact',function($scope){
    var akash  = "A simple message";
    $scope.akash = akash;
});
```

Here is the HTML.
the partial template location correct.
Here is the HTML.
the partial template location correct.
Here is the HTML.
the partial template location correct .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Appp">
<head>
    <title>Angular application with route</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="headed" align="center">
    <h1>Angular application with route</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="left">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#/add">Add contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/view">View contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/angular.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/angular-route.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/custom.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to tell  us what is the problem

Comment: I don't also know what is WRONG . BUT whenever i am trying to rub this code in XAMPP server the URL goes like this http://localhost/angularApps/#!#%2Fadd and the partial template is not injecting

Comment: post your html code

Comment: add with your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your , change it as,

```
 <div ng-view></div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/tuW3SsfBGh1WQP9OcAZK?p=preview)**

Comment: i also use <div ng-view></div> but the result are same

Comment: @AkashAhammad did you check the demo?

Comment: It's working but i hav to change local ANGULAR link to CDN

Comment: ok, probably you could check both angular-route and angular versions on local to make it work! glad to help